# Putting Declare Variable in String (of a Bulk Insert)

Tags: t-sql, ssms

trying to get an ETL package going which requires bulk inserting a bunch of .csv files off of a drive. Instead of manually having to scroll through the code and change the file path name for each insert (it increments with each month), would just like to declare the variable at the top.

Eg.

```
DECLARE @Month NVARCHAR(255)
SET @Month = 'November'

DECLARE @Year NVARCHAR(255)
SET @Year = '2019'

BULK INSERT #MonthlyMetrics
FROM '\\SomeServer\SomeFolder\Metrics_@Month_@Year.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
    , ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
    , FIRSTROW = 3
)
GO
```

There's a dozen of inserts like this where the only part of the file name that changes is the month. i.e. Metrics_November_2019.csv is that actual file name. Since the FROM is a string, not sure how to get the declared variable in there.

Comment: you will need to form the entire `BULK INSERT` query using `Dynamic SQL` and execute it using `sp_executesql` or `exec()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a dynamic SQL to load the data, only you will need to enable xp_cmdshell like this:

This turns on advanced options and is needed to configure xp_cmdshell

> `sp_configure 'show advanced options', '1';
>    RECONFIGURE`

This enables xp_cmdshell

> `sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', '1' 
>     RECONFIGURE`

After that you can load the data in your temp table:

```
DECLARE @dir                varchar(300) 
DECLARE @files              table (FileName varchar(800));
DECLARE @filesCmd           varchar(500);
DECLARE @filename           varchar(100);
DECLARE @cmd_BulkInsert     nvarchar(max);

SET @dir = '\\SomeServer\SomeFolder';
SET @filesCmd = 'DIR /b ' + @dir + ' | findstr csv';

INSERT INTO @files EXECUTE xp_cmdshell @filesCmd;

BEGIN TRY

    DECLARE C_TABLE CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY STATIC FOR
        SELECT FileName FROM @files WHERE NOT FileName IS NULL;
    OPEN C_TABLE;

    FETCH NEXT FROM C_TABLE INTO @filename;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SET @cmd_BulkInsert = N'
        BULK INSERT #MonthlyMetrics
        FROM '''+@dir+'\'+@filename+'''
        WITH
        (
             FIELDTERMINATOR = '',''
            ,ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a''
            ,FIRSTROW = 3
        )'
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @cmd_BulkInsert;

    FETCH NEXT FROM C_TABLE INTO @filename;
    END

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    SELECT
         GETDATE()
        ,ERROR_LINE()
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ,ERROR_NUMBER()
        ,ERROR_STATE()
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY()
        ,@cmd_BulkInsert

END CATCH
```